# How do I make @Controller mapping path configurable?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I'm building an internal library that should automatically add a few controllers to Spring MVC application. These controllers are all `@RestController` with a few handler methods annotated with `@RequestMapping`. Since it's a library, I want users to be able to specify the root path where the library should expose all these controllers. Illustration:

```
// given that I have a controller like this:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin") 
class AdminController {
  @RequestMapping("/users")
  UsersDto allUsers() { ... }
}

// it will be exposed at `http://localhost/admin/users`
```

What I want to achieve is to make `/admin` part configurable. For example, if user says in `application.properties`:

```
super.admin.path=/top/secret/location/here
```

I want `AdminController`'s handlers to be available at `http://localhost/top/secret/location/here`, and so the `allUsers()` handler should have a full path of:

```
http://localhost/top/secret/location/here/users
```

How do I achieve this? Feels like a pretty common task, but I didn't manage to find a straightforward solution that works.

#### My finding #1

There's a `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` mechanism that seems to be exactly what I want:

```
@Bean
public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping() {
    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
    simpleUrlHandlerMapping.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2);
    simpleUrlHandlerMapping.setUrlMap(Collections.singletonMap("/ANY_CUSTOM_VALUE_HERE/*", "adminController"));
    return simpleUrlHandlerMapping;
}
```

But it keeps saying

> The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler

#### My finding #2

There's Spring Boot Admin project that has this exact feature - you may configure where they should expose all their endpoints. They seem to have this functionality implemented from scratch in [PrefixHandlerMapping](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/blob/master/spring-boot-admin-server/src/main/java/de/codecentric/boot/admin/web/PrefixHandlerMapping.java). How they use it:

```
...
@Bean
public PrefixHandlerMapping prefixHandlerMappingNotificationFilterController() {
    PrefixHandlerMapping prefixHandlerMapping = new PrefixHandlerMapping(notificationFilterController());
    prefixHandlerMapping.setPrefix(adminServerProperties.getContextPath());
    return prefixHandlerMapping;
}
...
```

Comment: The `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` won't work for `@(Rest)Controller`. 2 is part of a 3rd party project and will map all your controllers. Just put the admin stuff in a different `DispatcherServlet` map `/admin` (or whatever they want) to that `DispatcherServlet` and be done with it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In addition to @M. Deinum solution, you can use *Path Patterns with Placeholders*. As [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-placeholders) states:

> Patterns in `@RequestMapping` annotations support `${…​}` placeholders
>   against *local properties and/or system properties and environment
>   variables*. This may be useful in cases where the path a controller is
>   mapped to may need to be customized through configuration.

So in your case, your controller would be like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/${super.admin.path:admin}") 
class AdminController {
  // Same as before
}
```

The preceding controller would use `super.admin.path` local/system property or environment variable value as its prefix or `admin` if those aren't provided. If you're using Spring Boot, by adding the following to your `application.properties`:

```
super.admin.path=whatever
```

You can customize that prefix.

Comment: Profiles do synergize very well with what you describe: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment

Comment: I tried the solution, but it doesn't work for me. The property within the value isn't resolved

Comment: Are using Spring Boot? Or plain Spring MVC?

Comment: Is there any chance to combine this with messages*.properties to build i18n url mappings?

Comment: great solution, worked for us, but another problem arose during testing. When testing our controller using MockMvc, it started to throw exception - invalid mapping. Apparently it cannot find the injected variable in MockMvc