# Request Mapping on a non predefined value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Suppose we have a simple spring listener:

```
@RestController
    public class App {
        /*Listener*/
        @RequestMapping(value = "/{String Value}", method = //some method )
        public String retVal( //PathVariables ) {
                 //code
        }
```

In this case String Value is a predefined string.

---

Is there any way to create a listener that has a **variable value** attach to the URL?

Comment: `private static final String STRING_VALUE = "/{String Value}"`?

Comment: In this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513117/how-do-i-make-controller-mapping-path-configurable), maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Like this you mean?

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/URL/{aParam}")
    public void aMethod(
        @PathVariable(value = "aParam") String aParam)
 {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@PathVariable` to do this.

```
@RestController
public class App {
   @RequestMapping(value = "/{StringValue}", method = //some method )
   public String retVal(@PathVariable(value = "StringValue") String StringValue) {
      System.out.println(StringValue); //it will print StringValue
   }
}
```

Refer this [How do I make @Controller mapping path configurable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513117/how-do-i-make-controller-mapping-path-configurable)

Answer (score 0):

As other have pointed out you can use Spring `PathVariable` annotation.
Additionally if the variable name you defined in the `RequestMapping` match the method argument name, you can write just `@PathVariable` instead of `@PathVariable(value = "variable")`.

```
@RestController
public class App {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{variable}"/*, method = some method */)
    public String retVal(@PathVariable String variable) {
       //code
    }
}
```